# How to refer to column 'BY' in query?

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google spreadsheet, i'm using the query function to get data from one sheet onto another. The query looks something like this:

`=QUERY('mySheet'!$A$1:100,"select F where "&C$3&"='myValue'")`

This works fine until cell C3 has value "BY" (because the word "by" has significance in the query language). I've tried using single quotes, but then the query uses header "BY" instead of column BY and it returns an empty result.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"BY" is a special word. It is present in clause `group by`

You may use this:

```
=QUERY({'mySheet'!$A$1:100},"select Col5 where Col"&C$3&"='myValue'", 0)
```

and paste the column number into `C$3`

see [more info here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

BTW you may use function `column()` to know `BY` is column 77 or find the right number by header name: `=match("column name", 'mySheet'!1:1, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The Col5 you proposed didn't work for me. However, i found that if you put the column name in between back-quotes (NOT single quotes) it works

Comment: Using back-quotes `` is also a documented feature. But I have not seen it in use before! You may add your answer with formula sample here, it'll help other people.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in backticks.

`` =sum(QUERY(select `BY` where `BY` is not null limit 7)) ``

This will sum the first 7 values in column BY.

*(This was fun to debug.  The formula worked in every other column...)*